# correlation table with number of observations N

Tags: r

I can get a correlation matrix with `cor()` but I do no know how to get the underlying number of observations. Is there a way?

```
#reproducible data
mydata <- mtcars
#add random missing
set.seed(17)
mydata[sample(x=nrow(mydata), size=5), "mpg"] <- NA
mydata[sample(x=nrow(mydata), size=5), "hp"] <- NA
mydata[sample(x=nrow(mydata), size=5), "wt"] <- NA
View(mydata)


#correlation matrix
cor(subset(mydata, select=c(mpg, hp, wt)), use="pairwise.complete.obs")
```

I would like a matrix, parallel to the correlation matrix, with these three values:

```
#N observations
cor.test(mydata$mpg, mydata$hp, na.action="na.exclude")$parameter + 2
cor.test(mydata$mpg, mydata$wt, na.action="na.omit")$parameter + 2
cor.test(mydata$wt, mydata$hp, na.action="na.omit")$parameter + 2
#or
nrow(na.omit(subset(mydata, select=c(mpg, hp))))
nrow(na.omit(subset(mydata, select=c(mpg, wt))))
nrow(na.omit(subset(mydata, select=c(hp, wt))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** Even shorter solution (by @akrun)

```
crossprod(!is.na(mydata))
```

---

Would the following get you what you want

```
res <- sapply(mydata, function(i) {!is.na(i)})
crossprod(res)
```

This results in

```
     mpg cyl disp hp drat wt qsec vs am gear carb
mpg   27  27   27 23   27 22   27 27 27   27   27
cyl   27  32   32 27   32 27   32 32 32   32   32
disp  27  32   32 27   32 27   32 32 32   32   32
hp    23  27   27 27   27 22   27 27 27   27   27
drat  27  32   32 27   32 27   32 32 32   32   32
wt    22  27   27 22   27 27   27 27 27   27   27
qsec  27  32   32 27   32 27   32 32 32   32   32
vs    27  32   32 27   32 27   32 32 32   32   32
am    27  32   32 27   32 27   32 32 32   32   32
gear  27  32   32 27   32 27   32 32 32   32   32
carb  27  32   32 27   32 27   32 32 32   32   32
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution of ekstroem is beautiful. I also just found out that the `psych` package has some nice functionality with the `corr.test()` function

```
library("psych")
corr.test(subset(mydata, select=c(mpg, hp, wt)), use="pairwise")
```